# confuse with generic parameters in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying something like this

[image]

I use it here

[image: cliente]

that is, I pass to Generic Method Print a list of Persons but inside the method, in data, I only have the standard methods of an object without any type.

How can I iterate the different kind of lists I will pass it?

Regards

Comment: Unles you don´t add a generic **constraint** the compiler will assume the most basic type for `T`, which is `object`. So you should add a `where T: MyType` to your method-signature. However we don´t know what types you expect for `T`. In your sample you have `List<Person>`, but I assume there are more. Otherwise a generic method would be pointless.

Comment: you need to tell the compiler what types you are expecting. otherwise, your data could be anything. and int, for example - and you can't iterate over an int.

Comment: Do your possible classes (e.g. `Person`) have *anything*  in common? Then you could extract a common base-interface for them and change your parameter to `Print<T> (string conceptop, IEnumerable<T> data) where T: MyInterface`.

Comment: Imagine you pass in a different type, what would you expect the method to do when it is expecting completely different properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a generic method without any constraint you say: this method works for **any** type, be it an `int`, `string` or even any arbitrary type like `MyType`. This is usually not what you actually want.

Instead you seem to have a very specific requirement: not just **any** type, but only a **few very specific ones**. In order to describe those specific types you can add a **generic constraint**. In your case the `data`-parameter seems to allways be some collection, e.g. a list, so let´s update your signature a bit:

```
public int Print<T>(string concepto, List<T> data) { ... }
```

Now you still have the same problem. You still have no specifics on what the elements within the list look like. They can still be numbers, strings, dates or whatever. You can now use this in your `Print`:

```
public int Print<T>(string concepto, List<T> data)
{
    foreach(var element in data) ... // element is of type T which is object
}
```

Actually you know that only a few types are possible, e.g. only `Person`. Ideally those types implement a common interface which you could use for the generic constraint:

```
public int Print<T>(string concepto, List<T> data) { ... } where T: MyInterface
```

This assumes all your possible types implement `MyInterface`:

```
class Person : MyInterface { ... }
```

Now you can access every member that is defined for that interface within your `print`-method:

```
public int Print<T>(string concepto, List<T> data) where T: MyInterface
{
    foreach(var element in data)
    {
        var myMember = element.MyMember; // element is of type T which is MyInterface
    }
}
```

Comment: for your last line ... a List still has no property "MyMember".

Comment: Nearly there, you probably meant `element.MyMember` :) Though the last example is also missing the type constraint.

Comment: Hi . Actually this was an example to know how to use generics but in my real applicaction I need to print IEnumerable<T> where T will be different kind of classes all of them with the same properties and one of these properties is an IEnumerable called CalendarioValores but when in my method I try this:  foreach (var item in data.First().CalendarioValores) the property "CalendarioValores" is not accessible

Comment: @kintela What generic constraint do you have now? Show the interface/base-class that matches the constraint.

Comment: Solved. I used an Interface and a constraint and now I find that property

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `Print` method to accept a generic type:

```
public int Print<T>(string concepto, IEnumerable<T> data)
{

}
```

Then, when you call it, pass the type, `Person` in this case:

```
 var result = repository.Print<Person>("subcontrationes", lista);
```